# What Adapter for bean Object?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I'm sending an bean Object from the first to the second View. Other times I use ArrayAdapter when I had an Array with data to show but this time I only have an bean Object that I want to show. What type of Adapter I must to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use any adapter, just pass the object itself. You can use the passed object in the activity directly, for setting the contents of the UI controls, for instance. You need adapters when you have a list of items. More information on this is provided on the class documentation of `Adapter` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Comment: Thanks. This is my code: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B04fsQs_GK3NV0JjQmZpeEFndDg but I have to do something else for show data in the View and I don't know.

Comment: I checked your code and didn't see the problem. What do you exactly want to do with this code, and you can't?

Comment: When I have the ImageView and the TextViews with data, I think that I must do something to show these. Something like view.show...(), one command to show the data on the View because these data don't appear on the View.